# Confusion about method of moments for linear regression

Tags: regression, method-of-moments, exogeneity

It is known that linear regression estimator can also be viewed as a method of moment estimator derived using the moment condition $E[X\epsilon]=0$. This moment condition follows from exogeneity assumption $E[\epsilon|X]=0$. But exogeneity assumption implies $E[h(X)\epsilon]=0$ for any $h(X)$ by law of iterated expectation. Why do we choose $h(X)=X$ specifically and not any other function of $X$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are talking of linear regression so it seems natural to consider the linear function?

Comment: @kevin012 Could you elaborate a little? I don't see how linearity in the coefficient $\beta$ relates to $h(X)$ being a linear function.

Comment: @RevealedPreference Could you add a proof that the exogeneity assumption $E[\epsilon | X] = 0$ and the law of iterated expectation imply that $E[h(X)\epsilon] = 0$?

Comment: @RevealedPreference I've posted this as a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477532/exogeneity-assumption-applied-to-functions-of-the-design-matrix).

Comment: @dwolfeu Sorry that I forgot to check on my question for the last few days. My proof for $E[h(X)\epsilon ] = 0$ would be similar to what you wrote in your question. $E[h(X)\epsilon ] = E[ E[h(X)\epsilon |X]] = E[ h(X)E[\epsilon |X]]$. $h(X)$ can be treated as a constant w.r.t. the inter expectation because it is a function of X.

Comment: @RevealedPreference No worries! Your proof makes sense; I was going round the houses trying to use the expected value of a product of random variables. If you give your proof as an answer to my question, then I can upvote it!

Comment: @dwolfeu Thanks. I will do that right away. Also thank you for your help on this question! I've upvoted your answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

The function $h(X)=X$ is used for the [GMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments#Scope) because it is equivalent to the OLS estimator, which by the [Gauss–Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) is the best linear unbiased estimator.

**The details**

We start with some notation to avoid any confusion with rows and columns:

\begin{equation*}
X =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & \ldots & x_{1p} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{n1} & \ldots & x_{np}
\end{bmatrix}
,\;\bar{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}
,\;\bar{\beta} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\vdots\\
\beta_p
\end{bmatrix}
,\;\bar{\epsilon} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_1 \\
\vdots\\
\epsilon_n
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

We assume that $X$ has full column rank.

Taking $h(X) = X$, the GMM conditions are

\begin{equation}
E\left[
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{j1} & \cdots & x_{jn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_1 \\
\vdots\\
\epsilon_n
\end{bmatrix}
\right]
= 0
\end{equation}

for $j \in \{1,\ldots,p\}$, i.e. the expected covariance of each column of $X$ with the errors is 0. We can put these $p$ conditions into one neat equation as follows:

\begin{equation}
E\left[ X^T\bar{\epsilon}\right] = \bar{0}
\end{equation}

(Here $\bar{0}$ denotes the zero vector.)

To find an estimate of $\bar{\beta}$ using the GMM, we need to minimise the sample estimate of $E\left[ X^T\bar{\epsilon}\right]$ with respect to $\bar{\beta}$, i.e. we need to find the value of $\bar{\beta}$ that minimises the norm of the following expression:

\begin{equation}
X^T\!\left(\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}\right)
\end{equation}

Notice that $X\bar{\beta}$ is in the column space of $X$, since it is a linear combination of the columns of $X$. Also note that $X^T\!\left(\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}\right) = \bar{0}$ if and only if $X\bar{\beta}$ is the projection of $\bar{y}$ on to the column space of $X$, since if $X\bar{\beta}$ is anything else in the column space of $X$, then the vector $\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}$ isn't orthogonal to the column space and thus the dot products in the expression $X^T\!\left(\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}\right)$ are not 0. The following diagram (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Projection)) illustrates this point:

[image]

We want to minimise $X^T\!\left(\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}\right)$ with respect to $\bar{\beta}$, which is clearly achieved when $X^T\!\left(\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}\right) = \bar{0}$. So we rearrange the equation $X^T\!\left(\bar{y} - X\bar{\beta}\right) = \bar{0}$ to find the necessary value of $\bar{\beta}$:

\begin{equation}
\bar{\beta} = \left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X^T\bar{y}
\end{equation}

But this is just the usual OLS estimator, which by the [Gauss–Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) is the best linear unbiased estimator.

Comment: Thanks dwolfeu! I guess the point is it happens to be the case that GMM estimator using $h(X)=X$ is exactly the same as OLS estimator. But we can also use general $h(x)$ to get a different estimator ( if sufficient conditions for convergence of GMM estimator are satisfied by $h(X)$)?

Comment: @RevealedPreference Precisely. One can indeed use a different $h(X)$, but it won't give you a better estimator (and might result in a function that is difficult to minimise).