# Exogeneity assumption applied to functions of the design matrix

Tags: regression, least-squares, expected-value, conditional-expectation, exogeneity

The context of this question is ordinary least squares. $X$ denotes the [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix#Definition).

I would like a proof of the claim – or a corrected version thereof – made in [this other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477051/confusion-about-method-of-moments-for-linear-regression/477275#477275) that the [exogeneity assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Classical_linear_regression_model) $E[\epsilon|X] = 0$ implies that $E\!\left[h(X)^T\epsilon\right] = 0$ for any function $h$ on $X$. (By "any function" I guess what is meant is an arbitrary function $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, where $n\times p$ is the shape of the matrix $X$.)

The claim for the special case $h(X)=X$ says that the errors are uncorrelated with the regressors, which we can be prove using [the expected value of the product of two random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Expectation_of_product_of_random_variables):

\begin{align}
E\!\left[X^T\epsilon\right] &= E_X\!\left[\vphantom{\sum}X^T E[\epsilon|X]\right] \\
&= E_X\!\left[X^T 0\right] \\
&= 0
\end{align}

However, if we try the same proof for the general case, then we seem to run into trouble:

\begin{align}
E\!\left[h(X)^T\epsilon\right] &= E_{h(X)}\!\left[\vphantom{\sum}h(X)^T E[\epsilon|h(X)]\right] \\
&\overset{?}{=} E_{h(X)}\!\left[\vphantom{\sum}h(X)^T E[\epsilon|X]\right] \\
&= E_{h(X)}[h(X)^T 0] \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Does the equality $E[\epsilon|h(X)] = E[\epsilon|X]$ hold if and only if $h$ is injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[h(X)^T\epsilon] = 0$ holds for any $h(X)$ because $h(X)$ can be treated as a constant when conditional on $X$. Using law of iterated expectations:

$E[h(X)^T\epsilon] = E[E[h(X)^T\epsilon|X]] = E[h(X)^TE[\epsilon|X]] = 0$

Answer (score 2):

This result is a consequence of the [law of iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).  Applying that law for any function $h$ gives:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(h(X)^\text{T} \epsilon) 
&= \mathbb{E} \Big( \mathbb{E}(h(X)^\text{T} \epsilon | X ) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E} \Big( h(X)^\text{T} \mathbb{E}(\epsilon | X) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E} \Big( h(X)^\text{T} \mathbf{0} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E} (\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}. \\[6pt] \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$